# restrict multiple login in different browser using a single account in laravel 5.5

Tags: session, authentication, laravel-5.5

For Example i want like - 
If user login from google chrome and trying to login from Firefox then **previous session should automatically destroy with a alert message**.
So far i have done below which is actually not the correct way because it's working fine with manually logout but when user logged out automatically because of session timeout or browser close or shutdown the db not update as it should be -

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) 
{
$previous_token = $user->token_id;
$token = $request->session()->token();
if ($previous_token == NULL) {
 Auth::user()->token_id = $token;
    Auth::user()->save();
 }elseif ($previous_token == $token) {        }
else
 {
  if ($previous_token != $token) {
        Auth::logout();
    }
    }
}

  public function logout(Request $request, User $user)
{
    Auth::user()->token_id = NULL;
    Auth::user()->save();

    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Please assist me on this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is another way just find out from laravel official documents which is - 
Need to un-commented in your app/Http/Kernel.php class' web middleware group:

`'web' => [
      \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
   ],`
and then 
 `protected function authenticated(Request $request)
    {
        $password = $request->password ;
        Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you want is to generate **new a random string/hash** (you can use the `str_random` helper function and optionally `Hash::make` to help you with that) as token whenever the user login, then store it in the DB and browser-side(**cookie**, so it is not affected by session timeout).

Then you can make a middle-ware or modify existing one to check if the two tokens are the same, and log the user out (and/or alert them) when they are not.

Since cookie is not shared by browsers, logging in with one will invalidate the token stored by the other, thus ending that session.

Comment: Thanks Pietro... But Still cannot find the solution can you please update my provided code if possible !

Comment: If the user logs in Firfox and without logging out closes the borwser and then comes back from a different browser, will he be able to login from the second browser ?